# Java Integer in a String range

Tags: java

So I have a string specifying a valid range of numbers .

for eg.

```
String range = "100-200 , 500 , 1000-1200";
```

Need to check if a given integer value is within this specified range
The range is different everytime.

Comment: parse the string properly, then you can check if the number is within any of the ranges

Comment: split the string by comma first and then by `-` and `Integer.parseInt` the numbers and check with `>` and `<`

Comment: is that the only way? Because i have to do this quite a lot of times.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552639 helps.

Comment: Then, like @Markus says: Use regex

Comment: I would recommend a different separator, though, since both -200 and -1200 are also valid Integer values

Comment: True , But can't really change the separators now . Been told to assume only positive values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first separate the different ranges. The valid ranges appear to be space-comma-space separated, so you need to split by `,`.

```
String[] ranges = range.split(" , ");
```

And then for each range you need to split it by a hyphen. As [Stultuske pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091608/java-integer-in-a-string-range#comment91133293_52091608), you have to take into account the fact that the hyphen itself could be part of the integer notation. If you expect only positive values, then you can split by a single hyphen:

```
String rangeStr = "400-600";
String parts = rangeStr.split("-");
```

Alternatively, if you expect also negative values, then you should split by the first hyphen that is not at the start of the string, and apply the split only once.

```
String rangeStr = "-1200--1000";
// Splits by hyphen which is not preceded by the start of the string.
// The resulting array has no more than two elements
String[] parts = rangeStr.split("(?<!^)-", 2);
```

Note that this also works if a single value is given instead of a range, e.g. `500`. Then, of course, `parts.length` is `1`.

And then you can get the ints by calling `Integer.valueOf(...)`.

---

Here is the code wrapped in a static method:

```
public static boolean inRange(String range, int value) {
    return Arrays.stream(range.split(" , "))
        .anyMatch(t -> {
            // Split the two integers denoting the range. The length of the
            // array is 1 if the range is an exact value (500 in your case),
            // otherwise, its length is 2
            String[] parts = t.split("(?<!^)-", 2);
            int minVal = Integer.valueOf(parts[0]);
            int maxVal = (parts.length == 2 ? Integer.valueOf(parts[1]) : minVal);
            return (minVal <= value && value <= maxVal);
        });
    }
}
```

And here some tests:

```
String range = "-2100--2000, 100-200, 500, 1000-1200, 2000-2100";
System.out.println(inRange(range, -2150)); // false
System.out.println(inRange(range, -2000)); // true
System.out.println(inRange(range, 400));   // false
System.out.println(inRange(range, 500));   // true
System.out.println(inRange(range, 1100));  // true
```

---

*Note that I have assumed that the source string is in the correct format. If you want to be a little more tolerant with what source string you expect (for example trailing spaces of multiple spaces in between), you have to implement that yourself.*

Comment: I believe he can also have a single value (like 500) as a value authorized.

Comment: @Nathan You're right, I will include that in my answer.